# Запретить создание записи, если пользователь является должником

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Всем привет, я новенький в MVC. В общем, я пытаюсь запретить выдавать книгу конкретному пользователю, если он является должником (то есть, если значение **DAYS LEFT** для конкретного должника равно 0 или отрицательное, то книгу не выдавать, а если положительное - выдать книгу), но не знаю как это можно реализовать.

Вот скриншот с примером, чтобы было яснее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался запретить создание записи так (первое if условие):

```
            if (orders.DateOrder.Day <= DateTime.Now.Day)
            {
                ViewBag.err = "This user is a critical debtor!";
                return RedirectToAction("Create");

            }

            if (orders.DateOrder > DateTime.Now || orders.DateOrder == null)
            {
                db.Orders.Add(orders);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Create");

            }
```

но такое условие, как и второе, лишь ограничивает создание записи с выбранной сегодняшней или прошедшей в текущем месяце датой, а не запрещает пользователю-должнику с конкретным Id выдавать книгу (создавать запись если из dropdownlist-списка юзеров выбран должник).

Как запретить создание записи, если пользователь является должником, и значение равно 0 или меньше?

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Если нужно сравнить даты без времени, то используйте `orders.DateOrder.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date`

Comment: @Jagailo Спасибо. Но как мне сделать это для конкретного юзера? Ведь я не указываю в условии юзера, потому что не знаю как написать условие чтобы запись не создавалась, если выбран конкретный юзер-задолжник, у которого значение равно 0 или меньше нуля.

Comment: Нужно к бд обращаться и получать информацию выбранного/текущего пользователя про его долги, а затем сравнивать

Comment: @Jagailo А как это сделать в MVC?

Comment: гулите, в интернете всё есть, на русском языке

Answer (score 0):

```
//класс для пользователя 
    class Users
    {
        public int userid { get; set; }
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public bool Banned { get; set; }
        public List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

        public bool CheckIfBanned()
        {
            if (Banned)// если у пользователя долги и он забанен
            {
                return true;
            }
            else // пользователь не забанен 
            {
                // проверяем его записи по книгам
                foreach (var b in books)
                {
                    if (b.daysLeft <= DateTime.Now)// есть запись с просроченной книгой
                    {
                        Banned = true; // ставим бан 
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;// записей с просроченной книгой нету
            }

        }

    }
    //класс с книгами
    class Book
    {
        public int bookId { get; set; }
        public string bookName { get; set; }
        public DateTime daysLeft { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но что делать если у меня daysLeft типа DateTime? Его же в int трудно перевести...Есть какое-то решение этой проблемы?

Comment: измените int на DateTime и проверку if (b.daysLeft <= DateTime.Now)